# Is there a prohibition against young boys being taught by women?

Tags: torah-study, age, gender

Isn't there a prohibition against young boys being taught by women? I swore I saw it in the tamud/midrash/tanakh/Torah but I can't seem to find it anymore.

Answer (score 3):

[Mishnah Kiddushin 4:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Kiddushin.4.13?lang=bi):

> וְלֹא תִלְמַד אִשָּׁה סוֹפְרִים
>
> A woman should not train to be a schoolteacher.

(See Bartenura ad loc. who interprets thus.)